# About the assertion "Your ruby code is never translated into machine language"

Tags: ruby, compilation, low-level

I'm reading the book Ruby under a Microscope, and I don't understand the quoted part in the second chapter:

From what I've understood, the process to run a ruby program is roughly the following

- Read the file and tokenize it
- Using grammar rules, transform those tokens into instructions in an Abstract Syntax Tree.
- Walking through the nodes, transform them into YARV bytecode (this step is called compiling?).

And this last one is the one that troubles me

- "Ruby never compiles your Ruby code all the way to machine language.
  [...] Ruby interprets the bytecode instructions."

My question is, for those bytecode instructions to be understood and executed, shouldn't I need to translate them into assembly/machine code before? If not, how does the machine understand them?

Comment: Do you know what an interpreter is?

Comment: @FUZxxl I understand it's a program that executes the code "as is", without compiling it, right? If that's the case, the question could be rephrased as asking how a (ruby) interpreter works, I believe.

Comment: How would you write an interpreter?

Comment: Your question can be better answered by reading text books on writing interpreters, and/or, searching for, and reading the many pages on the internet about Ruby's MRI. We don't know your expertise level and you didn't narrow down the question enough for a detailed answer, is so any answer we'd give would start at the very basics.

Answer (score 2):

> "Ruby never compiles your Ruby code all the way to machine language. [...] Ruby interprets the bytecode instructions."

That quote is – if not outright wrong – terribly misleading.

First off, Ruby is a programming language. Programming languages don't compile or interpret anything. Compilers and interpreters do that. Programming languages are just a set of abstract mathematical rules and restrictions.

Secondly, there are many different implementations of Ruby: [Rubinius](http://Rubinius.com/), [JRuby](http://JRuby.org/), [IronRuby](https://GitHub.Com/IronLanguages/main/), [MacRuby](https://GitHub.Com/MacRuby/), [MRuby](https://mruby.org/), [Topaz](http://TopazRuby.com/), [Cardinal](https://GitHub.Com/Parrot/Cardinal/), [Opal](http://OpalRb.org/), [MagLev](http://maglev.github.io/), [YARV](http://atdot.net/yarv/), … And they all work very differently. For example, Rubinius compiles Ruby to Rubinius bytecode, then it collects some statistics while interpreting that bytecode, and then it uses those statistics to compile the bytecode to efficient, performant, native machine code. JRuby interprets the JRuby AST and at the same time collects statistics, then it compiles JRuby AST to JRuby compiler IR, uses the statistics to optimize it, then compiles it further to JVM bytecode. What the JVM then does with that bytecode is up to the specific JVM implementation, but most JVMs will eventually compile JVM bytecode to efficient, performant, native machine code. Opal compiles Ruby code to ECMAScript code, and most ECMAScript implementations will eventually compile ECMAScript source code to efficient, performant, native machine code.

Thirdly, what does "machine language" even mean? YARV bytecode is the machine language of the YARV Machine, is it not? There are CPUs which can execute JVM bytecode directly, does that mean that JVM bytecode is machine language? There are [interpreters running on the JVM that can interpret x86 object code](http://jpc.sf.net/), does that mean x86 object code is not machine language? What if I run an x86 interpreter on top of [IKVM (a JVM running on top of .NET)](https://IKVM.NET/) on top of .NET on an ARM machine? What is machine language then?

So, to recap:

- Ruby is a language, not an implementation, the statement doesn't even make sense.
- Most Ruby implementations *do* (Rubinius, Topaz, MacRuby, MagLev) or at least *can* (JRuby, IronRuby, Opal, Cardinal) end up with native machine code.
- The term "machine language" is ill-defined anyway.

> My question is, for those bytecode instructions to be understood and executed, shouldn't I need to translate them into assembly/machine code before?

No, the interpreter understands and executes them. If it translated them into something else, it would be a compiler, not an interpreter.

A compiler translates, but doesn't run. An interpreter runs, but doesn't translate. You *need* an interpreter *somewhere*, you *cannot* get a program running with just a compiler. The compiler simply translates the program from one language to another language. Period. If you want to actually *run* the program, you need an interpreter. That interpreter may be implemented in hardware, in which case we call it a "CPU", but it's still just an interpreter.

See also [*Understanding the differences: traditional interpreter, JIT compiler, JIT interpreter and AOT compiler*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/269878/1352) over on Programmers.SE.

> If not, how does the machine understand them?

It doesn't. The interpreter understands them. It understands them in the same way that a compiler understands them, except that instead of *generating* code that corresponds to the semantics of the input program, it *runs* code that corresponds to the semantics of the input program.

See also [*Does an interpreter produce machine code?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/300639/1352) and [*How Does An Interpreter Work?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/323134/how-does-an-interpreter-work/323138#comment686277_323134) over on Programmers.SE.

Comment: I believe that the book refers to MRI as "Ruby", which I agree,  is a bit confusing. Thanks for your detailed answer!! I'll try to read all the links you've posted in these days. Would you mind responding a few more doubts about this?

Answer (score 1):

No, the statement you are in a quandary about alone speaks for itself. The Ruby byte code interpreter executes evaluations on behalf of the byte code and passes results (in most cases) to the next byte code set to be evaluated.

It is more complicated than that but think of it like a processing layer between the Ruby byte code and the native machine.